# JAXB - add binding to jaxb generated xsd schema programmatically

Tags: java, binding, xsd, jaxb, localdatetime

I'm trying to generate a xsd schema for my dto in java using JAXB Context, I managed to do that, but most of my dto use java.time.LocalDateTime so i need to implement an adapter. I figured how to do that via a xjb binding.
But the purpouse of this xsd is to be called from another project and I don't want to have the same xjb file replicated in every one.

Manually I wrote this xsd, that is my expected output:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="your-target-namespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"

           xmlns="your-target-namespace"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           jaxb:version="2.0"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:javaType name="java.time.LocalDateTime" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                              adapter="ar.org.hiba.adapter.LocalDateTimeAdapter"
                />
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType name="propiedadDTO">
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="aplicacion" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="entorno" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="estado" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="fechaUltimaModificacion" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:attribute name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="valor" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**ar.org.hiba.adapter.LocalDateTimeAdapter** is a class that I don't mind having in every project so that wont be a problem.

With this code snippet I generate a schema that doesnt have the global binding:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PropiedadDTO.class);
        SchemaOutputResolver sor = new OutputResolver();
        context.generateSchema(sor);
```

PopiedadDTO.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "propiedadDTO")
public class PropiedadDTO {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "aplicacion")
    protected String aplicacion;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "entorno")
    protected String entorno;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "estado")
    protected String estado;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "fechaUltimaModificacion")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected LocalDateTime fechaUltimaModificacion;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "nombre")
    protected String nombre;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "valor")
    protected String valor;

..getters and setters..
```

LocalDateTimeAdapter.java:

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter
        extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime v) {
        return v.toString();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="propiedadDTO">
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="aplicacion" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="entorno" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="estado" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="fechaUltimaModificacion" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:attribute name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="valor" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

That works great but when I run the jaxb plugin the attribute "fechaUltimaModificacion" is an XMLGregorianCalendar, and not LocalDateTime becouse I'm missing the global binding.

So, is there a way to add this few lines of xml to the xsd programmatically?
Maybe there is an annotation or property that I don't know about.

Thanks in advance.

edit: I added above the two java classes that get generated into the xsd output, see that I have the adapter annotation however the xsd output doesn't change.

Comment: The XSD is fine as is. You just need to implement an `XmlAdapter<String,LocalDateTime>` and add an @XmlJavaTypeAdapter on the field in your DTO.  See https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-dates for the code.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller I forgot to mention that I already have that annotation in de DTO pojo, see the edit in the post. With that annotations is that the last xsd I show is generated. I don't get any info at all about that adapter in the output xsd.